# NHibernate: uninitialized proxy passed to save() and cascade

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I keep getting an NHibernate.PersistentObjectException when calling session.Save() which is due to an uninitialized proxy passed to save().  If I fiddle with my cascade settings I can make it go away, but then child objects aren't being saved.

The only other fix I have found is by adding the following to my DefaultSaveEventListener.

```
    protected override bool ReassociateIfUninitializedProxy(object obj, global::NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor source)
    {
        if (!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(obj))
            NHibernateUtil.Initialize(obj);

        return base.ReassociateIfUninitializedProxy(obj, source);
    }
```

This is obviously not an ideal solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever found a better solution to this? At the moment I'm having to use the approach you've mentioned overriding the ReassociateIfUninitializedProxy.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: are you seeing this problem with allyour objects or one particular object. if its one particular object can you update the question with your model and mapping?

Answer (score 4):

There mere presence of a custom `DefaultSaveEventListener` subclass containing no overidden or extended behaviour is enough to trigger this exception for me, using the following configuration Xml:

```
<event type="save-update">
    <listener class="MyNamespace.MyCustomSaveEventListener, MyAssembly" />
</event>
```

I am continuing this discussion [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309390/bizarre-nhibernate-exception-uninitialized-proxy-passed-to-save-caused-by-f).

**Update:**

I had mistakenly derived from `DefaultSaveEventListener` instead of `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener`, changing the superclass made this problem go away for me.

Comment: Ahh stupid me I was deriving from `DefaultSaveEventListener` instead of `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener`, changing the superclass made this problem go away.

Comment: +1 - This was the cause - and fix - to my getting this error. I'd suggest moving your comment to your answer, cause it's helpful and an accurate reason why someone might get this error.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to work with a child object that is in a list on a root aggregate entity?  If you are, you need to work with the root, traverse to the child, make the changes, and save the *root*, not the child.

Comment: I'm not working on that project anymore, but I think that would probably be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

The fix was simple : `use ISession.Get()` and not `ISession.Load()`

Comment: I'm getting this error and I have no references to ISession.Load or any of it's overloads.